# How to limit gnus article buffer to specific time period?

Tags: gnus

When using Gnus, how can I display old messages from a certain time period in article buffer?

Comment: In summary buffer, does `/ t <days>` does what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Gnus Info page **Gnus > Summary Buffer > Limiting**

*Limiting* means you limit the summary buffer to just show some subset of the articles currently in the group. The particular command you are looking for is:

**‘/ t’**

```
 Ask for a number and then limit the summary buffer to articles
 older than (or equal to) that number of days
 (‘gnus-summary-limit-to-age’).  If given a prefix, limit to
 articles younger than that number of days.
```

(as Arash mentioned)